# Using multiple screens, how to switch spaces on all screens left or right

Tags: macos, screen

Assuming I am working on 3 screens, having 3 spaces on each screen.

How can I switch to the "left" space on each screen at the same time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only by not using  System Prefs > Mission Control > Displays have separate Spaces.

Once you do that, all 3 screens will 'share' the same space & switch together.

[image]

Personally, I find it a much better way to work, but I guess it will depend on personal preference. Using this method I like to 'tie' certain sets of applications together so I can see each 'set' on a different Space.

Each time you swap methods, all your carefully-prepared Spaces will mess up, as the numbering will change, so be prepared to have to reset which apps are set to open on which Space, if you wish to try it out.

Comment: Tried it out, but whenever i open an app in full screen, the rest of the screens go blank ... so basically i will need each app to work on a screen in the same space. is that possible? something like workspaces in Linux?

Comment: Ah, you need to not use fullscreen… as you discovered:( Fullscreen always steals a space for itself, which I find truly useless. I work maximised instead [alt/click the green dot, or just drag it to fill however much you need], then Spaces is great.

Comment: Yeah Apple didnt think this one... I kinda prefered workspaces in Linux where you can set each app to a screen and switch all together depending on what youre working at! same you need. thanks for the answer it helped :)